# My java code should make a list but it doesn't

Tags: javascript

My java code is not working I'm watching a code video for to do list this code should make a list when I click a button but it doesn't please help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Objiu.png)

```
<script>
document.querySelector('#push').onclick =

     function() {
    if (document.querySelector('#newtask input').
         value.length == 0){
alert("please enter  task");
       }
     else {

    document.querySelector('#task').innerHTML 
   += '<div class ="task"><span id ="taskname">$
   {document.querySelector("#newtask input").
   value}</span> <button 
   class ="delete">×</button></div>';
    }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: java and javascript are two different languages

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1:
createTextNode

Step 2:
Append it inside of body(I have done in #main for div)

```js
const main = document.querySelector("#main");
const inputText = document.querySelector("#textInput");
const taskBtn = document.querySelector("#addTask");

function addTask(taskData) {
  const task = document.createTextNode(taskData);
  main.appendChild(task);
  main.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
}
taskBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
  if (inputText.value == "") {
    alert("please enter task!!");
  } else {
    addTask(inputText.value);
    inputText.value = "";
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="main">
  <input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="Enter task" />
  <button id="addTask">Add task</button><br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

While the method in the accepted answer does produce the desired output, it doesn't answer the original question as to why the code does not work. There are actually a few things wrong with it:

- First, your click handler function declaration was missing it's closing `};`. You can catch mistakes like this by running your code through [linting tools](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-linting-and-how-can-it-save-you-time/) such as [JSHint](https://jshint.com/).
- Second, you should not brute force the `onclick` method of an element. Doing so only allows for one function to be attached. Instead you can use [Element.addEventListener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to attach a handler to the [`click`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/click_event) event.
- Finally, you tried to use a [placeholder expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals#string_interpolation)  `${...}` when setting `innerHTML`. These can only be used inside of [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals). The character used to create this type of variable should the backtick ( ` ) however, you have used single quotes ( ' ).

The correct way to write your code would be:

```
document.querySelector('#push').addEventListener('click', event => {
  if (document.querySelector('#newtask input').value.length == 0) {
    alert("please enter task");
  } else {
    document.querySelector('#task').innerHTML += `
      <div class="task">
        <span id ="taskname">
          ${document.querySelector("#newtask input").value}
        </span>
        <button class ="delete">×</button>
      </div>
    `;
  }
});
```